# href jQuery Colorbox issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, colorbox, href

I'm trying to get a ColorBox iFrame window to pop out of a page.  I am getting it successfully to pop out of the page but it almost instantly disappears.  I can't get it to stay on the page for the life of me let alone load anything in the window before it closes.

Here is what I have:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function OpenCBox() 
    {
        $.colorbox({href:"http://www.cnn.com", iframe: true, width: "80%", height: "80%", transition: "elastic"});
    }
</script>
```

This is my JavaScript function that calls OpenCBox() which performs the action.

This will pop out the window for like .2 seconds and then instantly disappear.  Don't understand what is going on.

```
 <asp:Button ID="NewRecordBTN" runat="server" Text="New Material Movement Request" 
        OnClientClick="OpenCBox()" />
```

I am driving myself crazy not being able to figure this out.  Any help would be excellent!

Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible that clicking the button is triggering an ajax postback and replacing the HTML for the colorbox?  Try this code and see if the box lasts: `<a href="#" onclick="OpenCBox(); return false;">Test CBox</a>`. If that works, then its very likely a postback is occurring.

Comment: Agree with Kranklin. Try using a normal HTML button instead.

Comment: Thank you so much! That normal HTML button worked flawlessly.  So weird that it acts like that.  Now that I think about it, it definitely looks like a postback is occuring when the colorbox is loading and cuts it off.

Comment: @se_brandon - Could you post your resolution as an answer and accept it so that future users who have the same question can find the answer quickly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took the above solution of adding a plain HTML button in rather than an ASP.NET button because of an autopost back that was firing.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function OpenCBox() 
    {
        $.colorbox({href:"NewMMR.aspx", iframe: true, width: "50%", height: "50%", transition: "elastic"});
    }
</script>
```

This function will take me to "NewMMR.aspx" in a ColorBox window.

And instead of using the above asp:button, I used the following:

```
 <input id="NewRecordBTN" type="button" onclick="OpenCBox()"
value="New Material Move Request" />
```

This resolved the issue because the normal HTML button didn't cause an autopostback.  Hope this can help someone else someday.